# Content disappears on mobile then appears when I zoom in (iphone 7, safari and chrome.)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iphone

I haven't seen anything like this before and not sure were to look to fix it. I created a website with standard HTML, CSS, Java, and has the magnific popup scripts. Whats interesting is that the rest of the website works fine its just the first 25% of the sites text doesn't show on a physical phone unless you zoom in. Everything shows fine on the developer tools on all devices.

[Header image before zoom (text is missing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwPEE.jpg)

[Header Image after zoom (until text randomly appears)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx19L.jpg)

HTML header / about section code and CSS @media screen code (error only happens on mobile)

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    text-align: Center;

}

p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', serif;
    color: #2C2C2C;
    font-size: 140%;
    line-height: 180%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-weight: 300;
}

.intro {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(img/Autumn-colors-mountain-sunset_-_Virginia_-_ForestWander.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    
}

.intro .inner {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: none;
    
}

.content {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2%;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 250px #000;

}

.content p {
    color: #fff;
    
}

.inner {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 170%;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding: 10px
        
}





@media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    #menu-icon {
        margin: 26px 0 0 26px;
    }
    nav ul, nav:active ul {
        padding: 8px 0;
        left: 23px;
        top: 34px;
        width: 50%;
    }
    .inner {
        font-size: 120%;
    }
    .content h1 {
        font-size: 180%;
    }
    p {
        font-size: 120%;
    }
    h2 {
        font-size: 160%;
    }
    .social{
         margin-left: -10%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="with=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>VOTING IS POWER</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/magnific-popup.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/ticket.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <!---- menu----->
    <section class="intro">
        <nav> 
            <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#register">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="#wedid">We did!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="inner">
            <div class ="content">
                <h1> “It gives you power.”<br/></h1><p>- Tammy, Richmond</p>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </section>
<!---------------------------ABOUT ---------------------->
    <a name="about">
<div class="clearfix"></div> 
   <section class="about">
       <h2 style="padding-top: 5%;">ABOUT</h2>
       <P style="text-indent: 6%; padding: 4% 2%;" >In 2016, Virginia Governor Terry McAuliffe restored the voting rights of over 200,000 citizens through a courageous executive order. As of earlier this year, only about 50,000 of those individuals were registered to vote.<br><br>
       The goal of this project is simple. We want to register - and turn out- as many NEW voters in the state of Virginia to vote in this year’s statewide election on November 7th. With your help, we can reach our goal of registering 25,000 new voters and turning out at least 100,000 voters to the polls on Election Day. Please support this campaign by sharing it first with everyone you know from Virginia, then with all of your friends and family on social media, and last, give what you can to help us reach as many Virginians as possible between now and November 7th. 
</P>
       <hr>
        
    </section>
```

Please let me know if there is anyway I can help you help me! And thank you for your time I do appreciate it!

Comment: You should post relevant portion of code which can be reviewed for bug. Please read through guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry about that, added header / about html and @media CSS.

Comment: What do you have in `<head>`?

Comment: I have added the <head> code as well as more CSS to the post!